# Installing a ceiling fan in a house built pre 50's

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

If I am installing a ceiling fan w/lights to an old house with only 2 wires coming out of the ceiling a hot (black) and white (neutral) is it necessary to connect the green ground wires from the fan to anything or can I just tape those off and call it good or do I need to put a cooper wire in. I only see 2 clothes wires that come from the ceiling there is not a box. I know the blue and black wires from the fan are connected to the black from the ceiling  and white to white.

Comment: What are "clothes wires"; is the box metal or plastic?

Comment: *There is not a box* is your bigger issue. A fan needs to be attached to a special, heavy duty box, and all electrical connections need to take place within a box. Anything else is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: There is no box. I wired everything in the casing between the ceiling and the fan.

Comment: Older cloth NM cable rarely had a ground. For a short while, late 50's-60's some had a small ~16ga ground which was typically wrapped back on the cable, but this did not provide a grounding conductor for the circuit. –  Speedy Petey

Answer (score 4):

## **First order of business: install an old work [ceiling](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Raco-RETRO-BRACE-with-1-1-2-in-Deep-Ceiling-Box-936/203743171) [fan](http://www.acehardware.com/product/index.jsp?productId=20350656) [box](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HEIYHA)!**

(The linked box is the first one that turned up on Google -- there are several makes and models of old work ceiling fan boxes available, all of the basic design depicted.)

Right now, not only are you violating NEC section 300.15,

> **Boxes, Conduit Bodies, or Fittings - Where Required.** A box shall be
>   installed at each outlet and switch point for concealed knob-and-tube wiring.
>
> Fittings and connectors shall be used only with the specific wiring methods 
>   for which they are designed and listed.
>
> Where the wiring method is conduit, tubing, Type AC cable, Type MC cable, Type 
>   MI cable, nonmetallic-sheathed cable, or other cables, a box or conduit body 
>   shall be installed at each conductor splice point, outlet point, switch point, 
>   junction point, termination point, or pull point, unless otherwise permitted 
>   in 300.15(A) through (L).

including the exceptions in (B),

> **Equipment.** An integral junction box or wiring compartment as part of 
>   approved equipment shall be permitted in lieu of a box.

(E),

> **Integral Enclosure.** A wiring device with integral enclosure identified for 
>   the use, having brackets that securely fasten the device to walls or ceilings 
>   of conventional on-site frame construction, for use with nonmetallic-sheathed
>   cable, shall be permitted in lieu of a box or conduit body.

and (H),

> **Insulated Devices.** As permitted in 334.40(B), a box or conduit body shall 
>   not be required for insulated devices supplied by nonmetallic-sheathed cable.

you have created a very nice **falling** ceiling fan **trap**!  Ceiling fans are *heavy* and require solid anchorage to two ceiling joists, or at least the solid-enough anchorage provided by a properly installed ceiling fan box.  Furthermore, without a box, an overheating or arcing splice can proceed to directly light your ceiling on *fire*!

Once you rectify the lack of a suitable box to mount the fan to, you can then wire black&blue to black, white to white, and leave the bare (or green) wire from the fan unhooked (or terminated to the green screw in the box if you're uncomfortable leaving a wire end floating -- it makes no difference electrically in your case, but may be preferable for mechanical reasons).

Comment: I'm renting this place so I knew nothing about the codes but I will be sure to let the landlord know